# Aforge PictureBox throws "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object is currently in use elsewhere.'"

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, aforge

Aforge PictureBox throws "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object is currently in use elsewhere.'" when I resize or move the application window.
In some situations it throws an Exception that indicates the use in several threads.

Exception

[image: 1]

Main Code:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
    
    //Global Var

        String[] serialLog = new String[300];
        SerialLogDisplay sld_form;

        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;

        //Form Method

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




    //Generated Methods

        private void btnCCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(cmbCameraS.SelectedIndex > 0) {
                disconnectVideoStream(false);
                videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cmbCameraS.SelectedIndex-1].MonikerString);
                videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
                videoCaptureDevice.Start();

                Add_Log("Camera \"" + filterInfoCollection[cmbCameraS.SelectedIndex-1].Name+ "\" Connected!");
            }
            else
            {
                disconnectVideoStream(true);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Camera System
            cmbCameraS.Items.Add("None");
            filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filterInfoCollection)
            {
                cmbCameraS.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            }
            cmbCameraS.SelectedIndex = 0;
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice();

            //Log
            shortLog.Parent = cameraDisplay;
            shortLog.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            shortLog.Text = serialLog[0] + "\n" + serialLog[1] + "\n" + serialLog[2];


            //Loop
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            tmr.Interval = 1000;
            tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
            tmr.Start();


            //DisplayObjects
            MPpanel.Parent = cameraDisplay;

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            disconnectVideoStream(false);
        }

        private void SLbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sld_form == null)
            {
                sld_form = new SerialLogDisplay(this);
            }
            sld_form.update_log(serialLog);
            sld_form.Show();
            sld_form.Activate();
        }




        //Created Methods

        //Serial Log
        private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String lm = "";
            for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (serialLog[i] != null)
                {
                    lm += serialLog[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
            shortLog.Text = lm;
        }

        public void SerialLogDisplay_Close()
        {
            sld_form = null;
        }

        public void Add_Log(String text)
        {
            for (int i = serialLog.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                serialLog[i] = serialLog[i - 1];
            }
            serialLog[0] = text;

            if(sld_form != null)
            {
                sld_form.update_log(serialLog);
            }
            
        }

        public void Serial_Command(String command)
        {
            Add_Log(command);
            //Send command to serial Port
        }



        //Camera Output
        private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cameraDisplay.Image != null)
                {
                    cameraDisplay.Image.Dispose();
                }
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                cameraDisplay.Image = bmp;
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Add_Log("Error: " + ex);
                disconnectVideoStream(true);
            }

            //GC.Collect();
        }

        private void disconnectVideoStream(bool showLog)
        {
            if (videoCaptureDevice.IsRunning == true)
            {
                if (showLog) { Add_Log("Disconnecting video stream..."); }
                videoCaptureDevice.SignalToStop();
                videoCaptureDevice.WaitForStop();
                videoCaptureDevice.Stop();
                cameraDisplay.Image = null;
            }

            if (showLog)
            {
                Add_Log("No camera connected!");
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

"CameraDysplay" -> PictureBox

I tried to put the Bitmap image as global, but it didn't work...
I also tried blocking the application window size change, but the error remains...

**I tried to use invoke and it worked, but it crashes when closing the application.**

```
        private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => {
                try
                {
                    if (cameraDisplay.Image != null)
                    {
                        cameraDisplay.Image.Dispose();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                    cameraDisplay.Image = bmp;
                }
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    Add_Log("Error: " + ex);
                    disconnectVideoStream(true);
                }
            }));
            //GC.Collect();
        }
```

Comment: You have [already asked this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74690737/7444103), the problem is still the same: don't access UI elements from a Thread other than the UI Thread Also, you MUST dispose of each Frame you receive. Try to follow the advice and use the method shown in my previous comment and read the notes there -- The text of exceptions and other details must be posted in plain text and in English

Comment: @Jimi 
I put this code that discards the images after using...
'''
                if (cameraDisplay.Image != null)
                {
                    cameraDisplay.Image.Dispose();
                }
'''

Comment: @Jimi
I read what you mentioned above, but I still don't understand what else I should do.
I must say that I have very little experience with AForge and Threads in C#.

I fixed the Bitmap and had it discarded after use and also started using Invoke to access the GUI thread.

With that several of the problems were solved, there was only one that from time to time makes the program stop working without throwing any exception.